# Switch between combox and radio buttons with CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to define HTML + CSS such that only a change to the stylesheet is needed to specify whether a choice is represented as a drop-down combobox or a list of radio buttons?

I suspect the answer to this is simply 'no' (which is perfectly acceptable as an answer, if backed up with evidence), but hopefully there's a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? Not cross-browser and very rough though, you could switch by simply changing the class.

***Demo Snippet***:

```css
select.radio {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    border: none; height: 1.5em;
}
select.radio, select.radio:focus { outline: none; }
select.radio > option { display: inline-block; }
select.radio > option::before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 12px; height: 12px;
    border: 1px solid gray; border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 4px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
select.radio > option:checked {
    color: #000;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ccc, #ccc);
}
select.radio > option:checked::before {
    background-color: #00f;
}

select.normal {
    width: 120px;
}
select { margin: 16px; }
```

```html
<select id="dl1" size="4" class="radio">
    <option value="One">One</option>
    <option value="Two" selected>Two</option>
    <option value="Three">Three</option>
    <option value="Four">Four</option>
</select>
<select id="dl2" size="4" class="normal">
    <option value="One">One</option>
    <option value="Two" selected>Two</option>
    <option value="Three">Three</option>
    <option value="Four">Four</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is sort of "No". You can't redefine a SELECT input a a list of radio buttons. However, you could create two divs with the separtae inputs contained within, and then display or not display based on CSS.

```
<style>
    #divSelect
    {
        display : none;
    }
    #divRadio
    {
        display : block;
    }
</style>

<div id="divSelect">
    <select id="MyChoice" name="MyChoice" size="1">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="divRadio">
   1 <input type="radio" name="MyChoice" value="1"/><br/>
   2 <input type="radio" name="MyChoice" value="2"/><br/>
   3 <input type="radio" name="MyChoice" value="3"/><br/>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this answer.  You don't even need the MyChoice id.  Here's a fiddle that iterates through the `MyChoice` names and gets the correct value based on its visibility:  http://jsfiddle.net/ef1e6wed/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can hide one or the other with CSS, but you will have to design your JS (or whatever is receiving this information) more robustly - Check both options and take data from the non-empty one.

Simply make one display and one not

**HTML:**

```
<div id="radios">
    bar <input type="radio" name="foo" value="bar"/>
    barbar <input type="radio" name="foofoo" value="barbar"/>
</div>
<div id="checks">
    <select name="bar">
        <option value="foo1">foo1</option>
        <option value="foo2">foo2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style>
    #radios{
        display:block;
    }
    #checks{
        display:none;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is style the css for all selects and then change the style for radio buttons.
Kinda like this

```
select {
  font-family: Cursive;
}

input[type=radio   ]{
  display      : inline-block;
  margin-left  : -28px;
  padding-left : 28px;
  background   : url('checks.png') no-repeat 0 0;
  line-height  : 24px;
}
```

here are some links that might help.
    http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/styling-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/
    http://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/